# jQuery Ajax Django: POSTs but no reply

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to setup a simple ajax message/response with jquery on Django. I manage to see *"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 7703* in the console, so I know the button is sending something. However, I can't figure out how to test the message being sent, or if any reply is making it back to the client.

edit: it seems this might mean that the javascript is posting to the "/" view ... but i'm not sure how to fix this

views.py:

```
def buttonformup(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('client_response'):
        x = request.POST['client_response']                 
        y = str(x)                        
        response_dict = {}                                         
        response_dict.update({'server_response': y })       
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        response_dict = {}       
        response_dict.update({'server_response': "failed no post" })             
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json')
    response_dict = {}       
    response_dict.update({'server_response': "failed completely" })             
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json') #should serve as ultimate failure point, but never gets here either
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button_up_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input_string = $("#subid").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/button_form_up/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                client_response : input_string,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
            success : function(json) {
                    $('#result').append( 'Server Response: ' + json.server_response);
                },
            error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

in template:

```
<form method="post" name="button_up_form" id="button_up_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="subid" name="subid" type="hidden" value="{{submission.id}}">
    <input type="submit" class="arrowup" value=""></input>
</form>
```

and `<div id="result"></div>` which never manages to get updated

urls.py:

```
url(r'^button_form_up/$', 'redparser.views.buttonformup', name='button_form_up'),
```

I've spent a day trying to fix this, trying different combinations of jscript and server side code from a variety of sources, but nothing seems to want to work, so here I am. Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to bind to the form's `submit` event, not `click`.

Comment: why not use a `print` in the views.py, check if the `buttonformup` is called.

Comment: @DanielRoseman good point, unfortunately it didn't solve the lack of reply issue